# Filename of captured image

Tags: qt, camera, qml, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

I'm working on an app which includes a camera function, but I can't figure out on how to get the filename from the captured image.

Is there an option in `QML` on how to get the filename of an image I just captured? If not is there any possibility to get the filename of the image just captured?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just use [`imageSaved`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#imageSaved-signal) signal inside `imageCapture` of `Camera`. Signal parameter `path` contains the physical path  you are searching for.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, There is one way to get the filename with path, i have also tried this.
Whenever you captured the image using --> camera.imageCapture.capture()      <-- then imageCaptured:{} is called and in imageCaptured{} you can used onImageCaptured:{} and here you can easily get the filename with path.
just write a one line of code.

For example:-

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    imageCapture {
         onImageCaptured: {
         var imgPath = camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath
         }
    }
}
```